# How to put a scroll view to many linear layout?

Tags: android, layout

I have designed this User Interface since it wont show the whole activity I want to put a scrollview to the layout.When I put in to a scroll view some buttons postion changes.how can I change it?

XML Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#3697dc"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/polonnaruwa"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/anuradhapura"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView3"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/dambulla"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:background="@drawable/kandy"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"

            android:background="@drawable/trincomalee"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"

            android:background="@drawable/galle"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:background="@drawable/colombo"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/hikkaduwa"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/yala"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/bentota"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:background="@drawable/nuwaraeliya"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"

            android:background="@drawable/ratnapura"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry If I don't get you, but I think this is what you need...

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.10"
android:fillViewport="true" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3697dc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="polonnaruwa" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="anuradhapura" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="dambulla" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="kandy" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:text="trincomalee" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:text="galle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="colombo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="hikkaduwa" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="yala" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="bentota" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="nuwaraeliya" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:text="ratnapura" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the view (layout) you want to scroll inside `<scrollView> </scrollView>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#3697dc"
    android:weightSum="1">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

<Relative Layout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/polonnaruwa"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/anuradhapura"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TextView3"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/dambulla"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:background="@drawable/kandy"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"

            android:background="@drawable/trincomalee"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"

            android:background="@drawable/galle"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:background="@drawable/colombo"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/hikkaduwa"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/yala"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@drawable/bentota"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3697dc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:background="@drawable/nuwaraeliya"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"

            android:background="@drawable/ratnapura"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </Relative Layout>    
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set fixed size to your `ScrollView`. In `XML` or calculate the height of all childrens in it, then sum and set to `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Put scroll View tag in the top of your views (listviews , linear ...etc)

make it width / height match parent

here is Example

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/GlobalLayout" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView1"
              android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
              android:layout_height="100dip"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
   <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView2"
              android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
              android:layout_height="100dip"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
   <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView3"
              android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
              android:layout_height="100dip"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```